# Flex4 - Microphone gain vs OS microphone input volume

Tags: flex4, voice-recording

I'm working on a Flex4 application that capture microphone input. Sometime recorded signal is too slow, or too high so is distort. I would like to have an initialization step before actually processing the audio to allow user to set up the best volume as possible. I've two solutions for that :

1. Have the user speak some sentences, calculate the volume level, and automatically adpat Microphone.gain in application code
2. Have the user speak some sentences, and show him a graphical representation of the volume and ask him to set up his OS microphone volume to get an acceptable level

Apart the user interaction required in solution 2, is one solution better than the user for the quality of the recorder audio, or are OS microphone volume and Flex micrphone gain the same ?

Comment: Just to be clear on terminology, "OS volume" is completely unrelated to the microphone gain in Flash. However, the OS usually has it's own "microphone gain" setting. I have found the two gain settings to be multiplicative. Answering your question about which approach to setting an appropriate gain is better is subjective. I would opt for solution #2 however, only because I think it's better for a user to decide what the right level is.

Comment: I firstly though that OS microphone gain may be more adequate than flex one because flex gain is just a increase in total signal, noise included. OS gain seems to be exactly same except for rare kind of microphone that have an internal gain system (and specific drivers), so I'll finally use Flex gain to automatically increase a too small OS gain, or show the user the OS volume helper if signal saturate even with small flex gain. Thank you for your feedback.